# Tabulator - get title of selected value from select editor

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the tabulator's select editor to update my database on value change, once this is updated I need to update my cell value to the title of the selected value and not the value itself. currently it is updating the value and not the title. 
is there a function or a method call to get the selected title from the select editor when the value changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this is built in function in the tabulator ,use the formatter ,make it "lookup" and send it the array of values in "formatterParams" as below

```
{  title: "Hi", field: "status", editor: select2Editort, editorParams: { values: StatusSelect }, formatter: "lookup", formatterParams: StatusSelect, minWidth: 120},
```

the extra code is 
**formatter: "lookup", formatterParams: StatusSelect**